# How can I debug a juju client command?

Tags: juju

I'm having issues bootstrapping with juju, where are logs that I can review?

Answer (score 1):

All commands accept both a `-v` and/or `--debug` flag that will produce a very verbose output. The former will output INFO level log information while the latter will produce DEBUG level output.

Here's an example bootstrap against an EC2 environment with both `-v` and `--debug` (`juju bootstrap -v --debug`)

```
2013-09-19 19:46:22 INFO juju.provider.ec2 ec2.go:209 preparing environment "ondina"
2013-09-19 19:46:22 INFO juju.provider.ec2 ec2.go:187 opening environment "ondina"
2013-09-19 19:46:22 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:29 reading tools with major version 1
2013-09-19 19:46:22 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:37 filtering tools by series: precise
2013-09-19 19:46:22 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:41 reading v1.* tools
2013-09-19 19:46:22 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:44 falling back to public bucket
2013-09-19 19:46:22 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:41 reading v1.* tools
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.10.0-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.10.0-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.10.0-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.10.0-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.10.0-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.10.0-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.0-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.0-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.0-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.0-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.0-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.0-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.2-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.2-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.2-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.2-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.2-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.2-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.2-saucy-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.2-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.3-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.3-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.3-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.3-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.3-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.3-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.3-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.4-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.4-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.4-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.4-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.4-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.4-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.4-saucy-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.4-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.12.0-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.12.0-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.12.0-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.12.0-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.12.0-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.12.0-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.12.0-saucy-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.12.0-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.0-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.0-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.0-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.0-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.0-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.0-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.0-saucy-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.0-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.1-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.1-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.1-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.1-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.1-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.1-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.1-saucy-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.1-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.2-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.2-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.2-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.2-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.2-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.2-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.2-saucy-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.2-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.3-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.3-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.3-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.3-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.3-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.3-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.3-saucy-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.3-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-saucy-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-saucy-armhf
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.10-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.10-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.10-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.11-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.11-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.11-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.12-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.12-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.12-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.13-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.13-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.13-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.14-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.14-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.14-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:23 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:93 picked newest version: 1.14.0
2013-09-19 19:46:30 INFO juju.environs.boostrap bootstrap.go:57 bootstrapping environment "ondina"
2013-09-19 19:46:30 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:29 reading tools with major version 1
2013-09-19 19:46:30 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:34 filtering tools by version: 1.14.0
2013-09-19 19:46:30 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:37 filtering tools by series: precise
2013-09-19 19:46:30 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:41 reading v1.* tools
2013-09-19 19:46:30 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:44 falling back to public bucket
2013-09-19 19:46:30 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:41 reading v1.* tools
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.10.0-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.10.0-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.10.0-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.10.0-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.10.0-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.10.0-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.0-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.0-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.0-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.0-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.0-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.0-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.2-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.2-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.2-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.2-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.2-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.2-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.2-saucy-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.2-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.3-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.3-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.3-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.3-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.3-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.3-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.3-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.4-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.4-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.4-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.4-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.4-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.4-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.4-saucy-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.11.4-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.12.0-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.12.0-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.12.0-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.12.0-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.12.0-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.12.0-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.12.0-saucy-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.12.0-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.0-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.0-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.0-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.0-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.0-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.0-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.0-saucy-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.0-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.1-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.1-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.1-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.1-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.1-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.1-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.1-saucy-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.1-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.2-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.2-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.2-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.2-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.2-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.2-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.2-saucy-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.2-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.3-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.3-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.3-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.3-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.3-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.3-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.3-saucy-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.13.3-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-precise-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-quantal-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-raring-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-saucy-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-saucy-armhf
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.0-saucy-i386
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.10-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.10-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.10-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.11-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.11-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.11-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.12-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.12-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.12-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.13-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.13-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.13-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.14-precise-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.14-quantal-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.9.14-raring-amd64
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:356 read metadata index at "http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/streams/v1/index.sjson"
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:491 candidate matches for products ["com.ubuntu.cloud:server:12.04:amd64" "com.ubuntu.cloud:server:12.04:i386"] are [0xc200476a80]
2013-09-19 19:46:31 DEBUG juju.environs.simplestreams simplestreams.go:836 finding products at path "streams/v1/com.ubuntu.cloud:released:aws.sjson"
2013-09-19 19:46:32 DEBUG juju.provider.ec2 ec2.go:393 ec2 user data; 11572 bytes
2013-09-19 19:46:34 INFO juju.provider.ec2 ec2.go:426 started instance "i-29949e50"
2013-09-19 19:46:34 INFO juju supercommand.go:284 command finished
```